# Issue reading from TXT file in Android

Tags: java, android, inputstream

My app has a java file named "`SituationActivity.java`". This activity is connected with question.xml. I also have a DAO class called `DAOQuestion.java`, where I read info from a text file called situation.txt. I seem to have done everything correctly, but when app loads on to question.xml with SituationActivity I cannot see the inscriptions from the file. I think my issue might be in my DAO class:

```
public class DAOQuestion {

Context context;

public DAOQuestion(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}

public ArrayList<Question> getAll() {
    ArrayList<Question> array = new ArrayList<Question>();

    AssetManager am = context.getAssets();

    try {
        InputStream is = am.open("situations.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, "$");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                Question q = new Question();
                q.end = Byte.parseByte(st.nextToken());
                q.situation = st.nextToken();
                q.button1 = st.nextToken();
                q.button2 = st.nextToken();
                q.true1 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                q.true2 = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
                array.add(q);

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return array;
}}
```

Also here is a part from the SituationActivity:

```
public class SituationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView situation;
Button button1;
Button button2;
static byte end;
static int true1;
static int true2;
DAOQuestion dao;
Question q;
ArrayList<Question> arr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);

    situation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.situation);
    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    dao = new DAOQuestion(this);

    arr = dao.getAll();
    q = arr.get(arr.size() - 1);
    situation.setText(q.situation);
    button1.setText(q.button1);
    button2.setText(q.button2);
    true1 = q.true1;
    true2 = q.true2;
    end = q.end;
```

Everything from Question.java:

```
public class Question {
String button1;
String button2;
String situation;
int true1;
int true2;
Byte end = 1;}
```

About app: here is TextView situation, Buttons button1 and button2. true1 and true2 are lines from which I should read on which line to go. So, one line in situation.txt is one layout(like one layout, just turn inscription). Problem: I cannot read from txt file!!!

Comment: What is the issue? What are you seeing that's different than expected?

Comment: I sad that i cannot see the inscriptions from the file

Comment: have you tried running your program step by step in a debugger?

Comment: What **do** you see? Can you [edit] with a screenshot? Can you add your XML file(s)? Can you add `Log` statements to your `getAll()` method? Please debug your code...

Comment: @njzk2 debbuger tells me that after the opening of this layout nothing happens. He does not seem to even get to the initialization